# Change radio button value to 'checked' (Vue.js, Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm a little new in Vue.js and currently I am having a problem with radios.
I have a form with different inputs. When I'm submiting the form I create a JSON file with all the form answers:

Instead of this output I want the value of the selected radio to be 'Checked'.

```
  {
     "pos_r_1":"Radio 1"
     "pos_r_2":"",
     "pos_r_3":"",
     "pos_r_4":"",
     "pos_t_5":"this a test",
  }
```

**LIKE THAT:**

```
   {
     "pos_r_1":"Checked"
     "pos_r_2":"",
     "pos_r_3":"",
     "pos_r_4":"",
     "pos_t_5":"this a test",
  }
```

How can I change the value of the radio to 'checked'?

**HTML**

```
 <v-form class="text-left" name="form" id="form">
    <v-radio-group
        v-model="checked"
        hide-details="auto"
        row
    >
        <v-radio
            v-for="radio in group"
            :key="radio.id"
            :id="radio.id"
            :name="radio.id"
            :label="radio.text"
            :value="radio.text"
        />
    </v-radio-group>
    <v-text-field
        id="pos_t_5"
        name="pos_t_5"
        label="Text"
        v-model="textfield"
    />
    <v-btn
        class="p-2"
        color="primary"
        elevation="11"
        @click="onSubmit"
    >click me</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

**Script**

```
export default Vue.extend({
name: 'Test',
data: function () {
    return {
        checked: '',
        textfield: '',
        group: [
            {id: 'pos_r_1', text: 'Radio 1'},
            {id: 'pos_r_2', text: 'Radio 2'},
            {id: 'pos_r_3', text: 'Radio 3'},
            {id: 'pos_r_4', text: 'Radio 4'},
        ],
    }
},
onSubmit() {
        this.loading = true
        const form = document.querySelector('form');
        const data = new FormData(form);
        let currentObj = this;
        let url = '/report/form/store';
        axios({
            url,
            method: 'post',
            data,
        }) .then(function (response) {
            currentObj.output = response.data;
        }) .catch( (error) => {
            if (error.response && error.response.status === 422){
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

})

I've tried to change the value of the Radios to 'checked' but that doesn't work because then when I click one radio all getting checked.
This is only an example of the form. The form will be big with more that 20 different questions.

**Update**
This is not the way to do it. I have to manipulate the value of the radios buttons inside a Form Model, where I will save all the form answers. Then I can change the value of the radio to 'checked' easier.

Comment: Can you show your `onSubmit` method?

Comment: I've edited my post with the Submit method

Comment: you are binding the value prop of v-radio to text property from group array objects which are set to 'Radio 1' and so on. that's why when you select one of them it sets the 'checked' to the 'Radio 1' and so on. I think you can achieve what you want with proper setting for value prop

Comment: @hamidniakan could you explain a little more on how to set it properly?Thank you

Comment: @SiaSeraf please explain more about what you are trying to achieve with the result generated from radio inputs so maybe I can help

Comment: @hamidniakan I edited my question again. I hope it is more clear now :)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, do you want to update the value inside `group` variable on change? Or do you want to update `checked` variable with the changed object?

Comment: I think it's realy creal what I wrote in the question. I want the output from the form(the JSON file where I save all the answers) for the selected radio value to be 'checked' and not the value from the radio.

Answer (score 0):

So, radio buttons works as it should to https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio.

If you need to send a request like `pos_r_3: Radio 3`, you have to do some transformation on it. I'd suggest the code like:

```
export default Vue.extend({
name: 'Test',
data: function () {
    return {
        checked: '',
        group: [
            {id: 'pos_r_1', text: 'Radio 1'},
            {id: 'pos_r_2', text: 'Radio 2'},
            {id: 'pos_r_3', text: 'Radio 3'},
            {id: 'pos_r_4', text: 'Radio 4'},
        ],
    }
},
onSubmit() {
        this.loading = true
        const form = document.querySelector('form');

        const data = new FormData(form); 
        for (let i = 0; i < this.group.length; i++){
            const currentGroup = this.group[i];
            data.set(currentGroup.id, currentGroup.text === this.checked ? 'Checked' : '');
        }

        let currentObj = this;
        let url = '/report/form/store';
        axios({
            url,
            method: 'post',
            data,
        }) .then(function (response) {
            currentObj.output = response.data;
        }) .catch( (error) => {
            if (error.response && error.response.status === 422){
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I have also other inputs in the form, that's why I have form data in the Submit method. I tryed what you said but I am having an error with the 'ckecked'  in (x => x.text === checked) =>  "checked is not defined"

Comment: sorry, use `this.checked` there

Comment: Thank you for you're answer but it doesn't change the value when I'm submiting the form.

  pos_r_2: Radio 2
  data: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: updated answer according to https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/set

Comment: Thank you  @SiarheiK  for your answer and the time but I have found what I have to do and it's something totally different. I've updated my question also :)